# Django auth/login problems

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm new to Django and trying to build a simple login system for my webpage using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` with Django 1.4.  I have a base template containing the following login form which is then extended by other template pages on my website:

```
<form method="post" action="/accounts/login/">
{% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
</form>
```

However when I try to login I get the following message:

> "Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure:
>       CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Relevant snippets from urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

and settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

.....

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
.....
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you view the page source, is `{% csrf_token %}` being rendered as anything?

Comment: No, nothing is being rendered for `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: can you try adding `django.core.context_processors.csrf` explicitly? or take a look with `djnago-debug-toolbar` if it's being activated.

Comment: Ah ok, problem solved.  I was using `render_to_response` and had to add  `csrf(request)` manually to the context.  Now I have switched to `direct_to_template` and the problem is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### simple login/logout system could be find [here](https://github.com/michaelarshinov/django_simple_backend_user_model)

Let me briefly explain how to use **standard auth** through the **user model** in Django:

***appname/views.py:***

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import 

@login_required
def stat_info(request):
return render_to_response('stat_info.html',
  {'is_auth':request.user.is_authenticated()},
  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def mainmenu(request):
return render_to_response('mainmenu.html',{},
  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

***urls.py:***

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^statinfo/$', 'appname.views.stat_info'),
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page' : '/accounts/login'}),
    (r'^mainmenu/$', 'appname.views.mainmenu')
)
```

***settings.py:***

```
...        
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/mainmenu/'
...
```

***templates/registration/login.html:***

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

***templates/base.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}templates/base.html{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="/accounts/login">Login</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
<div id="content">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***templates/mainmenu.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}templates/mainmenu.html{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    Mainmenu
    <a href="/statinfo/">stat info</a>
    {% endblock %}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**templates/stat_info.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}templates/mainmenu.html{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    Mainmenu
    <a href="/statinfo/">stat info</a>
    {% endblock %}

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

models:

class UserProf(models.Model):

```
"""
Create  ``RegistrationProfile for User``
"""
user = models.OneToOneField(User)

""" Other fields here """
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True)
age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

views:

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def user_authenticate(request):

```
"""
    check username and password and displays its appr. user_profile page
"""

username = password = ''
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('Password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/qioness/connect/')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/qioness/connect/')
```

urls:

url(r'^profile/$',show_detail),

template:

```
          <form action="/qioness/" method="post">
                       <label>

                        <strong class="email-label">Username</strong>

                        <input type="text"  id="Email" name="username">

                        <span class="login_error"></span>

                      </label>

                      <label>
                          <strong class="passwd-label">Password</strong>
                          <input type="password" id="Passwd" name="Password">

                          <span class="login_error">  </span>
                      </label>

                   <input name="Add" type="submit" value="Log" class="Submit_btn" />


                          <label class="remember">
                              <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="PersistentCookie" name="PersistentCookie">
                              <strong class="remember-label">
                                   Remember Me
                              </strong>
                          </label>
         </form>

       </div>
```

worked 4 me :)