# Django register and login - explained by example

Tags: django, forms, authentication, registration

Can someone please explain in details how to make a **registration** and **authentication** in as easy words as possible ? I made authentication (login) with `django.contrib.auth` but what I want to get is a full register(social/non)+login. Already saw the `django-allauth`, `django-social-auth`, `django-social` but still can't get it working without hacking a lot. Heard that `django-registration` and `django-profiles` can make it a lot easier, but i can't handle it. For example,

```
~/.virtualenvs/plinter/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/backends/default/urls.py
```

needs a small hack to work:

```
# from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
...
                           RedirectView.as_view(url='/registration/activation_complete.html'),
                           # direct_to_template,
                           # {'template': 'registration/activation_complete.html'},
...
```

The DjangoBook gives *simple* examples of [Contact and search forms](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html). But i can't expand it on user registration and login.
So can anyone give kis example of **working** **registration** and **login**?


## Update


[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180764/django-auth-login-problems) is a simple example of login. Now `django-allauth` or social auth or `registration2` are in consideration...


## Update2


`django-allauth` seems to be the best solution for easier authentication. Add correctly apps in settings, register fb/google/etc apps and register through admin and use template inheritance to change default pages design.

Comment: Why did you have to hack django-registration? Are you using django 1.5+? If so, don't install registration from pipy, it's not updated for compatibility. Install from [the bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/overview) instead .

Comment: Added `hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/downloads/django-registration-0.8.tar.gz` to `requirements.txt`, will try now.

Comment: no, that's the same version that is in pipy. Get the trunk instead of the tag: `hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration`

Comment: `$ pip freeze | grep django-registration`
`django-registration==0.8` - the same version which demands `simple` module. And it is weird because others also use this app with django-1.5...

Comment: The version you need is `(0, 9, 0, 'beta', 1)`. If you don't have that your installation is not compatible with 1.5

Comment: Try this: `pip uninstall django-registration` (Make sure you don't have any version of registration) `pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration#egg=registration`.

Comment: Yes, i've done uninstallation several times trying to figure out the problem. `$ yolk -V django-registration`
`django-registration 0.8`; so i've tried this one and it seems to be working one after ulrs syntax correction `$ pip search django-registration`
`django-registration2      - Registration and moderation utilites
  INSTALLED: 0.9.3 (latest)` but i'm still uncomfortable with login. need to read more about it.

Comment: glad you solved it. Login comes with contrib.auth, you can reuse the urls.py in `django.contrib.auth.urls` if you are ok with the given url names see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py).

Answer (score 13):

[THIS](http://code.techandstartup.com/django/registration/) is a **very good** tutorial about login & Co. It explains very well how to perform login by ourself ad override existing django login pages.

## UPDATE:

**Here Overview for Registration and Login. For more details go to the link.**

**To Register:**

> **Views and URLs**
>
> Go to the lower site folder (where the settings.py file  is) and open
>   the views.py file. At the top make sure the following  imports are
>   included. Add them if not:
>
> ```
> from django.shortcuts import
>  render_to_response from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect from
>  django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm from
>  django.core.context_processors import csrf
> ```
>
> Below that add the  following functions (you can put them after the
>   Login functions):
>
> ```
>  def
>  register(request):
>      if request.method == 'POST':
>          form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
>          if form.is_valid():
>              form.save()
>              return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register/complete')
>
>      else:
>          form = UserCreationForm()
>      token = {}
>      token.update(csrf(request))
>      token['form'] = form
>
>      return render_to_response('registration/registration_form.html', token)
>
>  def registration_complete(request):
>      return render_to_response('registration/registration_complete.html')
> ```
>
> Open the  urls.py file in the site folder (same folder as
>   settings.py). Below  urlpatterns = patterns('', insert the following
>   lines.
>
> ```
>      # Registration URLs
>      url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'simplesite.views.register', name='register'),
>      url(r'^accounts/register/complete/$', 'simplesite.views.registration_complete',
>  name='registration_complete'),
> ```
>
> **Templates**  We will assume your site  already has a templates
>   directory and a base.html file with the  navigation bar. Open the
>   base.html file and in the nav element add a  navigation menu link to
>   the login page
>
> ```
> <a href="/accounts/register">register</a>
> ```
>
> If one does not already exist,  go to the templates folder and create
>   a folder inside it named  registration. Create a file called
>   registration_form.html, save it to  the templates/registration folder,
>   then populate it with the  following:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Register{%
>  endblock %} {% block content %}
>
>    <h2>Registration</h2>
>
>    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
>      {{form.as_p}}   <input type="submit" value="Register" />
>
>    </form>
>
>  {% endblock %}
> ```
>
> Create a file called registration_complete.html, save  it to the
>   templates/registration folder, and populate it with the  following:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}You are
>  Registered{% endblock %} {% block content %}
>
>    <h2>Thank you for Registering</h2>   <p><a
>  href="/accounts/login/">Please Login</a></p>
>
>  {% endblock %}
> ```

**To Login:**

> **Views and URLs** Open the views.py file in the lower site folder (where the settings.py file is). If there isn't one then create and
>   save it. At the top of the file insert the following import: from
>   django.shortcuts import render_to_response Below that you only need to
>   add one function rendering the loggedin page. The other functions
>   (login and logout) are in the views.py file in the Django Auth folder.
>
> ```
> def loggedin(request):
>     return render_to_response('registration/loggedin.html')
> ```
>
> # Optionally, if you want to show their username when they login then call their username in the view. Change the loggedin function to:
>
> ```
> def loggedin(request):
>     return render_to_response('registration/loggedin.html',
>                               {'username': request.user.username})
> ```
>
> Open the urls.py file in the site folder (same folder as settings.py).
>   Below urlpatterns = patterns('', insert the following lines.
>
> ```
> # Auth-related URLs:
> url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
> url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
> url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'simplesite.views.loggedin', name='loggedin'),
> ```
>
> With simplesite being the name of the folder that holds the views.py
>   file that you are calling. Open the settings.py file and at the bottom
>   insert `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/loggedin/'`. Django's default
>   is to redirect to /accounts/profile when you log in, which is fine if
>   you have an profile page at that url. If not you need to change your
>   settings default for the Login redirect url to the one holding your
>   loggedin.html page.
>
> **Templates**
>
> We will assume your site already has a templates directory and a
>   base.html file with the navigation bar. Open the base.html file and in
>   the nav element add a navigation menu link to the login page `<a href="/accounts/login">login</a>` Add a logout link too `<a href="/accounts/logout">logout</a>` Create a directory called
>   registration inside the templates folder. If you do this through the
>   command line, type mkdir registration Create a file called login.html,
>   save it to the templates/registration folder, and populate it with the
>   following:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>
> <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
> {% csrf_token %}
> <table>
>   {{ form.as_table }}
> </table>
>
> <input type="submit" value="login" />
> </form>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```
>
> `{{ form.as_table }}` uses the Django Forms module to create the form.
>   You can create an unformatted form by using `{{ form }}` without the
>   HTML table tags, or have each field put inside paragraph tags with `{{
>   form.as_p }}`, or as an unordered list `{{ form.as_ul }}`. Optionally, you
>   can also lay out your own form structure and use the form field tags
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>
> <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
> {% csrf_token %}
>
> {% if form.errors %}
> <p>Your Username or Password were not entered correctly. Please try again.</p>
> {% endif %}
>
> <table>
> <tr>
>     <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
>     <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
>     <td>{{ form.username.errors }}</td> 
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
>     <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
>     <td>{{ form.password.errors }}</td>
> </tr>
> </table>
>
> <input type="submit" value="login" />
> </form>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```
>
> Create a file called loggedin.html, save it to the
>   templates/registration folder, and populate it with the following:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% block title %}Logged In{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>
>   <h2>You are logged in</h2>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```
>
> If you want to display the username, you would make the adjustment to
>   the view discussed in the views section. Then change the loggedin.html
>   template to the below (change the wording as you see fit):
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% block title %}Logged In{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>
> <h1>Welcome {{username}}</h1>
> <p>Thank you for logging in.</p>
> <p><a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a></p>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```
>
> Create a file called logged_out.html, save it to the
>   templates/registration folder and populate it with the following:
>
> ```
> {% extends "base.html" %}
> {% block title %}Logged Out{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>
>   <h2>Logged out!</h2>
>   <p><a href="/accounts/login/">Log back in</a></p>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It is not a simple thing to report the code if you look at the tutorial! I try to put some essential code...

Comment: @skyline75489: I hope that now the answer is acceptable, so please could you remove your downvote?

Comment: Actually I didn't downvote. I just came through this answer while doing reviewing.

Comment: Ok, I hope that they are correct and revise their downvote because that link is really very useful and it solved my days when I studied authentication.

Comment: Don't get upset, man. People downvote for so many reasons. Personally I feel that it would be more appropriate that you can put this link as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trix's approach worked for me, but the logout link was redirecting to the admin logout, instead of logged_out.html.

To fix the redirect, I added a next option to the href:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={% url 'loggedout' %}">Logout</a>
```

In templates/registration:

Renamed `logged_out.html` to `loggedout.html`; the underscore caused it to still route to the admin logout page.

In views.py:

```
def loggedout(request):
    return render_to_response('registration/loggedout.html')
```

And finally, in urls.py:

```
url(r'^myapp/loggedout/$', 'myapp.views.loggedout', name='loggedout'),
```